# Group and sort based on count of same value of a column and sort another column within those groups

Tags: sorting, awk

Assume I got this logfile:

```
100.1 500
100.2 501
100.2 501
100.2 501
100.1 501
666.2 501
300.1 555
300.1 501
100.1 300
100.1 300
100.1 300
102.3 500
202.1 500
301.2 300
```

Any duplicate lines should be removed first. Then swap the columns. And then group lines based on first column value (501, 500, etc), sorting such groups based on the count of these values. Finally, sort the second column value of such groups in descending order.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
$ awk '{!seen[$2, $1]++}; END {for (i in seen) print i}' $filename |
       sort -k2 -n -r
555?300.1
501?666.2
501?300.1
501?100.2
501?100.1
500?202.1
500?102.3
500?100.1
300?301.2
300?100.1
```

This is the expected output:

```
501 666.2
501 300.1
501 100.2
501 100.1
500 202.1
500 102.3
500 100.1
300 301.2
300 100.1
555 300.1
```

Comment: Your sample output is not sorted by any column, either ascending or descending. Also do you really want to swap columns?

Comment: I want to swap and keep unique entries, and then sort by both column in descending order

Comment: Then update your question to reflect what you said in this last comment.

Comment: the weird character is because you are using `$2, $1` to form the key, you can use `$2 FS $1` instead

Comment: Ah, yes that worked to remove the symbol. Thanks. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @klabbaparn Why `555 300.1` is at the end? Also update exactly the column to be considered first for sorting, "both" is not enough.

Comment: @thanasisp because it's has the least occurrences. So the 500, 501, 300 and 555 should determine the sorting order. The most occurrences in top.

Comment: @klabbaparn, does this `awk '!c[$1,$2]++{a[$2]++;b[$2]=(b[$2]?b[$2] ORS:"")$2 OFS $1} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc";for(i in a){print b[i]}}' Input_file` is near by what you want? Kindly check once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, it worked perfectly. Wow.. now I'm gonna have to digest this. Was much harder than expected,

Comment: @klabbaparn, Honestly your question is not clear. This was a guess(based on comments and I am still not fully sure if that worked for you :) ), please edit your question with correct details, thank you.

Comment: Question should be detailed enough now, I think. Added as accepted answer.

Comment: Note that when you use an array subscript with a comma, the values are joined with the awk SUBSEP variable. The default value of SUBSEP is octal 34, the ascii FS character. This accounts for the `?` in your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `awk` could you please try following, though I still not sure if OP needs it exactly this one. Since OP confirmed in comments that this worked so adding this an answer and requested OP to change question accordingly too.

```
awk '
!c[$1,$2]++{
  a[$2]++
  b[$2]=(b[$2]?b[$2] ORS:"")$2 OFS $1
}
END{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
  for(i in a){ print b[i] }
}
' Input_file
```

(Edit by Sundeep) I don't fully understand this myself, but this seems to work with `GNU awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"};
       !seen[$0]++{a[$2]++; b[$2][$1]}
       END{for(i in a) for(j in b[i]) print i, j}' ip.txt
501 666.2
501 300.1
501 100.2
501 100.1
500 202.1
500 102.3
500 100.1
300 301.2
300 100.1
555 300.1
```

Comment: this is close, needs to sort the second column in descending order

Comment: @Sundeep, :) ohhh but OP confirmed that it worked :) any edit you suggest are more than welcome cheers :) I will also check with OP on same once.

Comment: @klabbaparn, sure, request you to please do update your question then so that no one gets confuse :) this solution doesn't sort by 2nd column but takes care of rest of things mentioned by you.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: this is a Schwartzian transform.

```sh
sort -u file \
| awk '
    {count[$2]++; a[NR] = $1; b[NR] = $2}
    END {for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print count[b[i]], b[i], a[i]}
  ' \
| sort -nr -k 1,1 -k 3,3 \
| cut -d " " -f 2-
```

output

```
501 666.2
501 300.1
501 100.2
501 100.1
500 202.1
500 102.3
500 100.1
300 301.2
300 100.1
555 300.1
```

Comment: I'm using this solution, since it was easier to understand. However, I don't quite understand this part "-k 1,1 -k 3,3", I know it has something to do with sorting by keys(?)

Comment: Read the sort man page for all the details. That's saying: use the first column (count of occurrences) as the primary sort key, then use the 3rd column as the 2nd sort key.